# Java Swing make JSpinner stop adding up

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I am working on a little project for school right now, and I have a huge problem with the JSpinners I use. I have three JSpinners, which have a maximum value of 8 but all the numbers of the three JSpinners together must not exceed 20. So let's say the three Spinners are A, B and C and I have A and B already switched all the way up to 8, then C should only go up to 4. If I switch A back to 4, I could switch C all up to 8 and so on. The problem is, I can not find any method in the JSpinner supporting this. If anyone knows how I could achieve this, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

You may subclass `JSpinner` and override `getNextValue`, to do nothing (`return null`) in case the next value would be too high, do its usual stuff (`return super.getNextValue()`) if it isn't .

Register a `ChangeListener` on each of the `JSpinner`.

When a `ChangeEvent` occurs, simply recompute the current total.

Here is an example :

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Spinners implements ChangeListener {

    private int currentTotal = 15;
    private final int maxTotal = 20;
    private final JSpinner[] spins = new JSpinner[3];

    public Spinners() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(5, //initial value
                    1, //min
                    10, //max
                    1); //step
            JSpinner spinner = new AutoBlockSpinner();
            spinner.setModel(model);
            spinner.addChangeListener(this);
            spins[i] = spinner;
            content.add(spinner);
        }

        computeCurrentTotal();

        frame.setContentPane(content);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();

    }

    private void computeCurrentTotal() {

        currentTotal = 0;

        for (JSpinner spin : spins) {

            currentTotal += (Integer) spin.getModel().getValue();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(final ChangeEvent e) {

        computeCurrentTotal();

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        Spinners spinners = new Spinners();

    }

    class AutoBlockSpinner extends JSpinner {

        @Override
        public Object getNextValue() {

            if (currentTotal + 1 <= maxTotal) {
                return super.getNextValue();
            } else {
                return null;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that creates a custom `SpinnerModel`. Each model is then linked to other models to form a group.

Basically the code is overriding the `getNextValue()` method of the `SpinnerModel` to determine if you are at the maximum or not. The value is only updated when you are below the group maximum.

You can only increase the spinners to a total value of 10:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GroupSpinner
{
    private int groupMaximum;

    private List<GroupSpinnerNumberModel> models = new ArrayList<GroupSpinnerNumberModel>();

    public GroupSpinner(int maximum)
    {
        this.groupMaximum = maximum;
    }

    public SpinnerNumberModel createGroupModel(int value, int minimum, int maximum, int step)
    {
        GroupSpinnerNumberModel model = new GroupSpinnerNumberModel(value, minimum, maximum, step, this);
        models.add( model );

        return model;
    }

    public Object getNextValue(int currentValue, int step)
    {
        int maximum = getGroupValue() + step;

        if (maximum > groupMaximum)
        {
            return currentValue;
        }
        else
        {
            groupValueUpdated(maximum);
            int nextValue = currentValue + step;
            return nextValue;
        }
    }

    public int getGroupValue()
    {
        int maximum = 0;

        for (GroupSpinnerNumberModel model: models)
        {
            maximum += model.getNumber().intValue();
        }

        return maximum;
    }

    private void groupValueUpdated(int value)
    {
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    public class GroupSpinnerNumberModel extends SpinnerNumberModel
    {
        private GroupSpinner model;

        public GroupSpinnerNumberModel(int value, int minimum, int maximum, int step, GroupSpinner model)
        {
            super(value, minimum, maximum, step);

            this.model = model;
        }

        public Object getNextValue()
        {
            int currentValue = super.getNumber().intValue();
            int step = super.getStepSize().intValue();

            return model.getNextValue(currentValue, step);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1) );

        GroupSpinner group = new GroupSpinner(10);

        JSpinner number1 = new JSpinner( group.createGroupModel(0, 0, 10, 1) );
        panel.add(number1);
        panel.add( new JSpinner( group.createGroupModel(0, 0, 10, 1) ) );
        panel.add( new JSpinner( group.createGroupModel(0, 0, 10, 1) ) );
        panel.add( new JSpinner( group.createGroupModel(0, 0, 10, 1) ) );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JSpinnerModel like this:

```
SpinnerModel sm = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 8, 1);
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(sm);
```

You need a Change Listener for all JSpinners. When you increase or decrease a Spinner, you increase/decrease the sum of all thre Spinners. You can add a ChangeListener like that:

```
aSpinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
    //count and update here
    }
});
```

Then you iterate over the JSpinners and create a new SpinnerModel for each of them, with the new Maximum value and set it to the JSpinner.

For Example:
A:8, B:7, C:0. You are now increasing B to 8, then your total is 16.
You create a new SpinnerModel and add it to the JSpinner for C:

```
 SpinnerModel sm = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 20-16, 1);
 cSpinner.setModel(sm);
```

I hope, that helps!

Comment: Hum, changing the model instances will lose previous selections even when perfectly (then-)valid values were selected.

Comment: You can add the old values as default value in the Model Constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But wouldn't this require a really big amount of different models? Let's say I switch the first A to 7 and B to 7 then the maximum value for C would be 6. I would have to write a model for every possible combination, or am I wrong?

Comment: Have a look at @Berger. His answer is a better solution. I didn't saw the getNextValue() function.

Comment: But additional to my answer: You dont have to create a big amount of different models. Each time, when you modify one of the spinners, you create 2 new Models for the two other spinners. You can create them dynamicly and override the existing instances. But again: @Berges solution is better.

Comment: @GAlexMES I prefer camickr solution. It is closer to my understanding of MVC and won't bewilder other listeners to the model(s). Stability has some nice sides.

Comment: @LaurentG He did the thing I tried to explain. But I would recomend you Bergers solution. It is better.

Comment: @GAlexMES this is a model consistency matter, not an a view/presentation matter, so my preference still goes to camickr's.

Comment: Do it how you like. Bergers solution is just nicer. It represents more of the OOP thinking.